# Python : Get word from string where substring is present in string

Tags: python, python-re

I am new to Python and still learning basic concepts of it.
I was wondering if there is any easy way to get all the words from a sentence where my search string matches the substrings of any words.

```
sentence = "Hi this is just an example.com sentence"
search = ".com"
```

Output :

```
example.com
```

I tried to use *re* module but got stuck at point where I need to fetch the whole word. This is what I have tried which returns the whole sentence as output:

```
re.findall(f".*{search}*", sentence)
```

I wanted to know if I am using the right approach or if there is any other way to solve this.

**Additional Question :**

Using reference of John's answer, `[w for w in sentence.split() if '.com' in w]`
I am able to get the expected output.
As an additional requirement, if

```
sentence = "Hi this is just an Example.COM sentence"
```

I still want it to match with .com and return Example.COM

Comment: `re` could work but seems like overkill. You could just use `[w for w in sentence.split() if '.com' in w]`

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for this answer. I was moving in `re` direction so forgot the basics. Additional question : If the sentence is `"Hi this is just an example.COM sentence"` I still want it to match with `.com` and return `example.COM`

Comment: @TestLearner That would be an important detail to mention in your question.

Comment: Updated the question with additional question section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider what pattern have you created

```
sentence = "Hi this is just an example.com sentence"
search = ".com"
print(f".*{search}*")
```

gives output

```
.*.com*
```

that does match any character (`.`) repeated zero or more times (`*`) followed by any character (`.`) followed by single character `c` followed by single character `o` followed by character `m` repeated zero or more times.

I would use `re` following way in this case

```
import re
sentence = "Hi this is just an example.com or example.COM sentence"
search = ".com"
found = re.findall(f"\\w*{re.escape(search)}\\w*",sentence,re.IGNORECASE)
print(found)
```

gives output

```
['example.com', 'example.COM']
```

Explanation: I use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) so `.` in search is treated as literal dot, not any character, I am looking for search prefixed and suffixed by zero-or-more (`*`) word characters (`\w`) and do that in case-insensitive way using `re.IGNORECASE` flag.

Comment: Good catch! As in Diego's answer, one could avoid doubling up on slashes by using a raw string (`rf""`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regexs (*perhaps you are planning for more complex searches*)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re

sentence = "Hi this is just an example.com sentence, don't match dotcom"
search = "\\.com"

print(re.findall(f"\\b(\\w*{search})\\b", sentence))
```

this matches the word boundaries (`\b`),
result

```
['example.com']
```

Comment: Could avoid doubling the slashes with a raw string , `r""`

Answer (score 0):

Using re package:

```
import re
c = re.compile(f"[A-Za-z]+{search}")
c.findall(sentence)
```